# why I need to add hostname to docker when creating a volume

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm creating a rabbitmq container with the -v option to add a volume, the weird part is that if I don't add the --hostname the container is no getting the information of the volume, for example:

I create a volume like this:

```
docker volume create --name rabbit
```

Later I verify that the volume is created

```
docker volume ls
```

Then I create the container like this:

```
docker run --name rabbitprueba -P -p 55555:15672 -d -v rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.10-management
```

I enter to localhost:55555 and enter user and password, then I create a simple queue, I return to my machine and stop and remove the container:

```
docker stop rabbitprueba
docker rm rabbitprueba
```

when I run the same command:

```
docker run --name rabbitprueba -P -p 55555:15672 -d -v rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.10-management
```

The queue that I created is gone but if I repeat the same steps (stop container and remove it) and add to the command the --hostname the queue is not removed:

```
docker run --hostname rabbitprueba --name rabbitprueba -P -p 55555:15672 -d -v rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.10-management
```

Why this is happening?, Am I doing something wrong?,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you are doing nothing wrong, but you are assuming the problem to be with docker. The problem is how rabbitmq saves its data.

When you launch a rabbitmq container using below command

```
docker run -it rabbitmq:latest
```

You will notice in docker logs a line showing

```
Database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@51267ba4cc9f is empty. Initialising from scratch...
```

Next run:

```
Database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@5e9c67b4d6ed is empty. Initialising from scratch...
```

So you can see it creates a folder based on the hostname. Now if i run

```
docker run -it --hostname mymq rabbitmq
```

And the log would show

```
Database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@mymq is empty. Initialising from scratch...
```

So that is what is happening here. Not a problem with volume, but just the way rabbitmq works. It is possible for you to change the name of this config using environment variables like below

```
 docker run -it -e "RABBITMQ_NODENAME=mq@localhost" rabbitmq
```

And logs would now show

```
Database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/mq@localhost is empty. Initialising from scratch...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, is very helpful.